# create empty row in dbgrid

Tags: oracle11g, delphi-7, dbgrid

I wanted to insert several lines to database using DBGrid.
on my query, I selected for example:

> select * from cust where id='0';

that code will return no record at all so my dbgrid will not show anything but an empty row. Now I wanted to put in data in empty row with new data. However my data needs 2 lines from dbgrid. I wanted dbgrid creates an empty row right after I fill last column in first row. How do I code that? (without inserting the first row data because later I'll insert everything with a seperated button).
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can add records in your table with `NULL`in each column.
For example, suppose the table where the DBGrid is binded to has 4 columns, than you can try this code to add empty records

```
Query1.InsertRecord([null, null, null, null]);
```

With this code you can add as many empty records as you like in the DBGrid
That is assuming that the query component you are using supports the `InsertRecord` method...